# Allow filtering elements by fields on related elements in element indexes

Tags: control-panel, relations

I'm trying to show some additional columns in the entry index, and allow editors to filter and sort by them. The problem is that the fields that need to be used for sorting are set on *related entries*, not on the entries themselves.

Some more detail: I have a section `registrations` which tracks user registrations for courses. Registration entries have only two fields:

- An *Entries* field `course` limited to one related entry from the `courses` section.
- A *Users* field `participant` limited to one related user.

The `courses` entries have fields for `location` (Entries field with a relation to an entry in the `locations` section) and `start_date` (Date field). Now the client needs to be able to filter `registrations` by the location and date of the `courses` entry they are related to – but those fields only exist on the `courses` entry, so they don't appear in the available columns in the entry index.

One obvious solution is to add those fields to the `registrations` entries as well, but that feels wrong. I'm duplicating the data, and there's a chance of entries becoming inconsistent. This can again be solved using hooks, but that's a lot of unnecessary work.

I've tried to use `Element::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES` and `Element::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML` to add the two columns for location and date to the entry list. This works, but it's not possible to filter by those columns, which is required in this case.

I'm not sure how best to solve this. I also thought about programmatically adding a tab to the `courses` section's field layout that just lists all related `registrations`. But it should also be possible to export the list of registrations, which we would get 'for free' if we can manage to enable filtering by those related element fields in the entry index.

What's the best approach to solve this? Is there a way to add columns to element indexes that can be filtered and sorted by?